# IOS 13.3 Client Certificate Authentication Safari is requesting certificate multiple times after a header 302

Tags: ios, authentication, ssl, certificate, ios13.3

I have a web application that uses client certificates installed on iPhones (iOS 12, iOS 13) to authenticate the users.

We have the web server set up to request optionally the certificate (because not all our clients have the certificate)

Apache is the webserver with the 
    
`SSLVerifyClient optional
SSLVerifyDepth 3
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars`

flags used.

As of the release of iOS 13.3, (13.2, 12 was ok) every time (for about 5 times) we respond with a 302 header safari asks for the certificate, (the user is prompted).

In the end the server seems to take it on board and stop prompting the user.

Any idea if the issue is with the certificate on the device or with the apache config?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As TLS client cert is part of the handshake with TCP... do you set `Keep-Alive` on the connection?

Comment: Hi, we have tried modifying the Kepp-Alive and it did make a difference.Thanks! However the client was prompted less often for the certificate but still multiple times.

Comment: Are you running in `per-server context`? Otherwise renegotiation might happen on the HTTP 302 Location target... https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient

Comment: the SSLVerifyClient is per server (dedicated machine)

Comment: Seems like either client or server interrupt the connection on the redirect. Without a network trace there is little change to find the root cause.